# ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.explored the existing solutions

Tags: python

Was running my Python program and I received this error:

```
3 fits failed with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 680, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/neighbors/_classification.py", line 198, in fit
    return self._fit(X, y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/neighbors/_base.py", line 400, in _fit
    X, y = self._validate_data(X, y, accept_sparse="csr", multi_output=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 581, in _validate_data
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 964, in check_X_y
    X = check_array(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 794, in check_array
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

My code looks like this:

```
# evaluate each model in turn
results = []
names = []

for name, model in models:
    kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, random_state=1, shuffle=True)
    cv_results = cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold, scoring='accuracy')
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    print('%s: %f (%f)' % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std()))
```

Comment: What is your question about all of this?  And how is the code related to the stack trace?

Comment: How do I solve this error?

Comment: Not enough info to match error to posted code.